# How to add remote event receiver to already created document library in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, event-receivers

I have a document library which has different folders in it like Task 1 , Task 2 etc. Whenever user uploads a file inside any folder lets say Task 1 , i want to assign file property(Task Name) as Task 1 . I tried this with SharePoint Designer Workflow but it is taking time for calculations . Is there any way to do this ? I am thinking about Synchronous Remote Event Receivers .Any kind of suggestion will be helpful .

[image]
[image]

Comment: Take a look at Column default value settings, that may fulfill your requirements. You can set the default values on individual folders. If the folders are non-static and you really want to automate it, look up Remote Event Receiver examples.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Aveenav . Folders are non-static, which gets created due to  other workflows. In this conditions default value settings will not help.

Comment: I tried Remote Event Receivers(RER) but RER is applied for the list & libraries which are created during creation of RER only . Is there any way by which we can add RER to already created list/libraries for sharepoint online ?